# How to get tabId in chrome extension from tabs.query

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that takes the URL from the active tab, finds another tab in the current window through `tabs.query`, and will log something to console when found.

My question is, how to a get the tabId from the variable that stores the tabs.query?

```
      //click button to trigger event
      $('#geturlbutton').on('click', function(){
        console.log('geturlbutton clicked')

        //get current URL for for active tab
        chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tabs) {
          currentURL = tabs[0].url;
          console.log(currentURL);

          //find the tab with mywebsite
          villageTab = chrome.tabs.query({url: "*://*.mywebsite.com/*"}, vilTab);

          //once found run function to execute script in mywebsite tab
          function vilTab(tabs){
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(villageTab.tabId,{  <-- this is where error occurs
              code: "console.log('executeScript worked');"
            });  
          };

        });
```

The `chrome.tabs.executeScript(villageTab.tabId,` is clearly not the way to get the tabId of that object. Please tell me how to get the tabId so I can execute a script in that tab?

Comment: The first `.query` is correct, but then you somehow forget it's async and try to use its direct return value. See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)